# Understanding Namebench Response Distribution Chart

Tags: dns, google-public-dns

After a long test I get this result:

[image: namebench result google public dns]

[image: namebench response distribution chart]

As a final number I see that Google Public DNS is 171% faster than my current DNS, but when I look at this picture I see that `SYS-192.168.0.1` the fastest in... short durations? As I understand - for some domains `SYS-192.168.0.1` is much faster than Google Public DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For some domains SYS-192.168.0.1 is much faster than Google Public DNS?

`SYS-192.168.0.1` is likely to be your gateway or router as `192.168.0.1` is a private (local) IP address.

It will be faster for any DNS lookups that have been locally cached.

There is nothing in that graph that appears to refer to 171% ... so I don't know where you are getting that number from ...

Comment: Added screenshot with `171%`.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich So what is your current primary DNS server?

Comment: Looks like my cheap router `TP-Link TL-WR841N` cache some DNS?

Comment: My primary DNS was not set, I do not know, maybe from ISP.

Comment: `nslookup` will show your DNS ...

Comment: In `nslookup` I see `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: So your gateway/router is your default DNS. As my answer says it is probably caching DNS queries.